# UIDocumentInteractionController Does Not Show Mail Option

Tags: ios, ios7, uidocumentinteraction

Heres the UIDocuemtnInteractionController from my application(does not show mail option)
[image]

Here the one that Apples sample project uses
[image]

Here are the respective codes

My application

```
docInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
[docInteractionController presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender animated:YES];
```

Apple Sample Project

```
NSURL *fileURL;
if (cellIndexPath.section == 0)
{
    // for section 0, we preview the docs built into our app
    fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:documents[cellIndexPath.row] ofType:nil]];
}
else
{
    // for secton 1, we preview the docs found in the Documents folder
    fileURL = [self.documentURLs objectAtIndex:cellIndexPath.row];
}
self.docInteractionController.URL = fileURL;

[self.docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:longPressGesture.view.frame
                                                   inView:longPressGesture.view
                                                 animated:YES];
```

WHAT SHOULD I DO TO GET THE MAIL OPTION?

Comment: What type of file are you trying? Show us your fileURL code?

Comment: is the mail app available on your device ?

Comment: @GenieWanted Here is the description of file URL 

Printing description of fileURL:
file:///Users/Name/Library/Application%20Support/iPhone%20Simulator/7.1/Applications/A0DC474B-790F-47DD-9DAA-F1B85A161DDD/Documents/Download/Important%20News%20About%20Your%20Taxes.pdf

Comment: @KIDdAe, YES.... And both the above application(My application and Apple sample application) were running on the simulator. So I suppose if apple sample could show it, even my application was supposed to show it.

Comment: Did you try changing the presentOptionsMenuFromRect to presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated?

Comment: Also, try using [docInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES]; and see if that really makes an impact? I have this same line of code in my app and it does work (shows the mail app)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To provide the `Mail` option, `-presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:` needs to be `-presentOptionsMenuFromRect:`

As per the [Apple Docs on `UIDocumentInteractionController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html)

For `-presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:` it says:

> This method is similar to the
>   **`presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:animated:`** method, but presents a
>   menu restricted to a list of apps capable of **opening** the current
>   document. This determination is made based on the document type (as
>   indicated by the UTI property) and on the document types supported by
>   the installed apps.
>   ...
>   If there are no registered apps that support opening the document, the
>   document interaction controller does not display a menu.

### So:

1. To present options to **open** the file, use `-presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem:`
2. To present all possible options applicable on the file, use `-presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:` or the generic `-presentOptionsMenuFromRect:`

---

Also... for any file, it would be better to specify the [UTI](http://www.escape.gr/manuals/qdrop/UTI.html) type:

### Example:

```
docInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
//[docInteractionController setDelegate:self];
[docInteractionController setUTI:@"public.data"];
[docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender 
                                                animated:YES];
//or a generic method
//[docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:sender.frame
//                                            animated:YES];
```

Comment: In your example, I think you mean: `[docInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem*)sender animated:YES];`.  As it is now, this won't compile or run.

Comment: I have a similar situation but I want to show the mail option too so I can't use presentOpenInMenuFromBarButtonItem. But presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem does not work on iOS 8 (must be a bug). So what can I do?