# Show UIDocumentInteractionController from share button in nav bar - iOS

Tags: ios, image, tableview, uidocumentinteraction

In my project I'm using [WSAssetPickerController](https://github.com/w5mith/WSAssetPickerController).

Despite the toolbar not working (not a huge issue), everything is working fine.

I have added a share button in the view controller, but I can't seem to get the UIDocumentInteractionController to get called, I tried copying the same method I'm using for files saved in the apps folder (which works fine). But here it's not.

How the irrelevant Downloads page works:

```
NSString *fileName = [directoryContents objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *path;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Downloads"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

documentController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];
[documentController setDelegate:self];
[documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
```

How the images get loaded:

```
#pragma mark - Fetching Code

    - (void)fetchAssets
    {
        // TODO: Listen to ALAssetsLibrary changes in order to update the library if it changes. 
        // (e.g. if user closes, opens Photos and deletes/takes a photo, we'll get out of range/other error when they come back.
        // IDEA: Perhaps the best solution, since this is a modal controller, is to close the modal controller.

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

            [self.assetsGroup enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *result, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {

                if (!result || index == NSNotFound) {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                        self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [self.assetsGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName]];
                    });

                    return;
                }

                WSAssetWrapper *assetWrapper = [[WSAssetWrapper alloc] initWithAsset:result];

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                    [self.fetchedAssets addObject:assetWrapper];

                });

            }];
        });

        [self.tableView performSelector:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.5];
    }
```

How I load and call the button:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Loading";

    UIBarButtonItem *shareButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAction
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(shareAction:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = shareButton;
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;


    // TableView configuration.
    self.tableView.contentInset = TABLEVIEW_INSETS;
    self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.tableView.allowsSelection = NO;


    // Fetch the assets.
    [self fetchAssets];
}
```

Should and did select fetched assets

```
#pragma mark - WSAssetsTableViewCellDelegate Methods

- (BOOL)assetsTableViewCell:(WSAssetsTableViewCell *)cell shouldSelectAssetAtColumn:(NSUInteger)column
{
    BOOL shouldSelectAsset = (self.assetPickerState.selectionLimit == 0 ||
                              (self.assetPickerState.selectedCount < self.assetPickerState.selectionLimit));

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    NSUInteger assetIndex = indexPath.row * self.assetsPerRow + column;

    WSAssetWrapper *assetWrapper = [self.fetchedAssets objectAtIndex:assetIndex];

    if ((shouldSelectAsset == NO) && (assetWrapper.isSelected == NO))
        self.assetPickerState.state = WSAssetPickerStateSelectionLimitReached;
    else
        self.assetPickerState.state = WSAssetPickerStatePickingAssets;

    return shouldSelectAsset;
}

- (void)assetsTableViewCell:(WSAssetsTableViewCell *)cell didSelectAsset:(BOOL)selected atColumn:(NSUInteger)column
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Calculate the index of the corresponding asset.
    NSUInteger assetIndex = indexPath.row * self.assetsPerRow + column;

    WSAssetWrapper *assetWrapper = [self.fetchedAssets objectAtIndex:assetIndex];
    assetWrapper.selected = selected;

    // Update the state object's selectedAssets.
    [self.assetPickerState changeSelectionState:selected forAsset:assetWrapper.asset];

    // Update navigation bar with selected count and limit variables 
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.assetPickerState.selectionLimit) {
            self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%lu/%ld)", [self.assetsGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName], (unsigned long)self.assetPickerState.selectedCount, (long)self.assetPickerState.selectionLimit];
        }
    });

    if (self.assetPickerState.selectedCount == 0) {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
    }
    else {
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
    }

}
```

Work needed to below with example from the download code I have used before.

```
-(void)shareAction:(id)sender {

        //Launch UIDocumentInteractionController for selected images

        documentController =[[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc]init];
        documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath://Code needed here??//]];
        documentController.delegate=self;
        [documentController presentOpenInMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];
}
```

What would be the best practice to do this?

Thanks.

UPDATE 8/4:

```
-(void)shareAction:(id)sender {

        //Launch UIDocumentInteractionController for selected images
    if (self.assetPickerState.selectedCount >= 1) {


        documentController = [[UIDocumentInteractionController alloc] init];
        documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"public.image"]];
        [documentController setDelegate:self];
        [documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero inView:self.view animated:YES];

    }

}
Returns: Unable to get data for URL: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `interactionControllerWithURL:` doesn't seem to be a problem but I have observed that `-presentOpenInMenuFromRect:` does not show if there are no apps that can ***open*** the file.

If your purpose is to *share* the file, and generally that doesn't mean *open* the file in the conventional sense, then instead of:
`-presentOpenInMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`
use
`-presentOptionsMenuFromRect:inView:animated:`

The former is an `OpenInMenu` and latter is an `OptionsMenu`.
<sup>For the tiny difference, check my [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23339460/2857130) or check [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html) directly</sup>

---

### Example:

```
//this seems fine
documentController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]];

//do this
[documentController presentOptionsMenuFromRect:CGRectZero 
                                        inView:self.view
                                      animated:YES];
```

---

**Also...**, just before you present the `documentInteractionController`, it's good practice to specify the file's `UTI` so the `documentInteractionController` can populate itself with the appropriate options that can be performed & the list of all apps that can handle this file:

Example:

```
//assuming the file is a PDF
[documentController setUTI:@"com.adobe.pdf"];

//or... same thing but a more standardized way would be
[documentController setUTI:(NSString *)kUTTypePDF];
//but for this second style you'll need to add the `MobileCoreServices` framework
//to your project bundle and specify the following in your .h or .m
//#import <MobileCoreServices/MobileCoreServices.h>
```

---

**Extra:** [Apple's Uniform Type Identifiers Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/UTIRef/Articles/System-DeclaredUniformTypeIdentifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009259-SW1)

Comment: Ill give that a try when i get home. But the thing is that it isn't a specific file. Its the selected asset that's being selected. I.e the images from the ohoti library that you helped in my last question.

Comment: @ChrisOSX : sure, no issues. anyways... for images, you can use `@"public.image"` as the UTI instead. Also, for clarity purpose, `NSLog` the `path` variable and specify that in your question.

Comment: I get the error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 260.) when I use the updated code shown in question.

Comment: @ChrisOSX : good sign but now the `URL` is incorrect. **you have** `[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"public.image"]];` but **you need** `[UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path]]];`

Comment: @ChrisOSX : **Note:** `@"public.image"` is the `UTI` and never the `URL`. I hope I didn't confuse you unnecessarily.

Comment: No you didn't confuse me :) The only confusing part right now is trying to define the path to the images in the photos library.

Comment: @ChrisOSX : hm.. alright, then... `NSLog` `path` after `path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];` and add path string to your question.