# Disable right bar button when selected equals 0

Tags: ios, tableview, navbar

The below code for the most part works when selecting items, the bar button enables, but as soon as I unselect 1 with say 3 still selected, it disables.

How can I use the below code to disable when the count reaches 0 items selected?

```
- (void)assetsTableViewCell:(WSAssetsTableViewCell *)cell didSelectAsset:(BOOL)selected atColumn:(NSUInteger)column
{
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];

    // Calculate the index of the corresponding asset.
    NSUInteger assetIndex = indexPath.row * self.assetsPerRow + column;
    WSAssetWrapper *assetWrapper = [self.fetchedAssets objectAtIndex:assetIndex];
    assetWrapper.selected = selected;

    // Update the state object's selectedAssets.
    [self.assetPickerState changeSelectionState:selected forAsset:assetWrapper.asset];

    // Update navigation bar with selected count and limit variables
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        if (self.assetPickerState.selectionLimit) {
            self.navigationItem.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ (%lu/%ld)", [self.assetsGroup valueForProperty:ALAssetsGroupPropertyName], (unsigned long)self.assetPickerState.selectedCount, (long)self.assetPickerState.selectionLimit];
        }
    });
}
```

Below is what needs adjusting.

```
if (selected == 1) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
} else if (selected == 0) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`selected` will give you the state of the current `asset` so it wouldn't be wise to check this.
We need to check for some kinda global thing; basically to check for previous selections.

Looking at your `navigationItem.title`, it seems `assetPickerState.selectedCount` should do the trick.

So... maybe this?? <sup>(not sure but anyways...)</sup>

```
if (self.assetPickerState.selectedCount == 0) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
}
else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect. I see what I was doing wrong. Thanks for the input and correct answer.

Comment: I have another question about a somewhat related topic here if you wouldn't mind taking a look. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25107543/show-uidocumentinteractioncontroller-from-share-button-in-nav-bar-ios

Comment: @ChrisOSX : sure, i'll look into it in awhile

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're only explicitly enabling the button when you have 1 selected (not more than that).  Just going out on a whim but this might work (only disable if zero, otherwise enable it).

```
if (selected == 0) {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
} else {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = YES;
}
```

Comment: Right track, but staticVoidMan ended up nailing it with the self.assetPickerState.selectedCount in the statement.